# Prove that an isometry f maps the circle c with center P and radius r onto the circle c' with center f(P) and radius r.

Tags: geometry, discrete-mathematics

I know proving an isometry maps circles into circles. However, proving an isometry maps circles onto circles is somewhat similar to the proof of circles into circles. Any hints on how to start this proof? Also, if possible, can I assume the inverse of f, knowing that a bijection is into and onto and then apply what I am trying to claim isometry maps circles onto circles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This result follows pretty directly from the fact that, in the metric space $(X,d)$, a circle with center $P$ and radius $r$ is defined as the set $C_P^r = \{x\in X:d(x,P)=r\}$ and that isometries preserve distance. The proof has two parts, the details of which I'll hide below:

1. Show that if $f$ is an isometry of $(X,d)$ then $f^{-1}$ is an isometry of $(X,d)$.

> Let $f$ be an isometry of $(X,d)$. Since $f$ is a bijection by definition, it has an inverse $f^{-1}$. To show that $f^{-1}$ is an isometry, we need to show, given any two points $x,y\in X$, that $d(x,y) = d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y))$. Since $f$ is an isometry, we have that $d(f^{-1}(x),f^{-1}(y)) = d(f(f^{-1}(x)),f(f^{-1}(y))) = d(x,y)$. Thus $f^{-1}$ is an isometry.

2. Prove that $f(C_P^r)\subseteq C_{f(P)}^r$.

> For a point $y\in f(C_P^r)$ there exists some $y'\in C_P^r$ such that $y = f(y')$. Then $r = d(y',P) = d(f(y'),f(P)) = d(y,f(P)) = r$, so $y\in C_{f(P)}^r$, proving the result.

3. Lastly, show that $C_{f(P)}^r\subseteq f(C_P^r)$ by using step $(2)$ with $f^{-1}$.

> *(You got this one!)*

Comment: Hi. This may be a bit of an elementary question, but I was just curious. Why do we write $f(C_P^r) \subset C_{f(P)}^r$ instead of $f(C_P^r) = C_{f(P)}^r$? Is it because an isometry is mapping a point, and that point may be on the circle? Also, why is it necessary to show the inverse case as well?

Comment: @Seankala Good question! Here, the goal is to prove that $f(C_P^r) = C_{f(P)}^r$. To that end, I’m employing the standard technique to show that two sets are equal by proving containment in both directions.

Comment: In step 3 how would you use $f^{-1}$ with step 2 I don't understand, like proving that $f^{-1}(C_P^r)\subseteq C^r_{f^{-1}(P)}$??